# Can't bind to ngModel even though FormsModule has been imported

Tags: angular, angular5

I am following the get started tutorial [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1) and I have gotten up to putting in the first input field. I added the FormsModule to the AppModule, yet it continues to display the error "ng Can't bind to '{ngModel}' since it isn't a known property of 'input'"

Hero Compoent HTML:

```
<div>
 <label>Name:
  <input [{ngModel}]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
 </label>
</div>
```

App Module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I know there are plenty of other questions that are similar and I have worked off of them, but my problem is that their solution is not working for me.

Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
[{ngModel}]
```

With following

```
[(ngModel)]
```

For your reference `[()]` is called as banana bracket

Answer (score 1):

You need parenthesis instead of brackets:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
```

Comment: I really should have picked that up...Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Things like this happen to me all the time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use **`[(ngModel)]`** instead of `[{ngModel}]`.

Also make sure that you are using correct syntax.

**It is case sensitive**. I was using [(ngmodel)] (*all in small letters*) and it was giving same error.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not correct. Use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[{ngModel}]`

Sample:
`<input [(ngModel)]="value">`